# How to run multiple Where clauses using laravel models in a switch statement

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model, eloquent

I have a `switch` statement that I want to query my `Database` based on `case clauses`; and I want to use **`Where clauses`** to achieve my goal. I want to incrementally add where clauses to my `User` model based on satisfied conditions.
example :

```
switch($key){
    case 'province':
        //User::where('province', '=', $value);
        break;
    case 'city':
        //User::where('city', '=', $value);
        break;
    case 'specialty':
        //User::where('specialty', '=', $value);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I want to use **Eloquent Models** instead of Query Builder. but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
// instantiate the query
$query = User::query();

// add wheres
switch / foreach or whatever
{
   $query->where(...);
}

// other methods if needed
$query->orderBy(..)

// execute
$users = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add clauses incrementally, a loop would be better than a switch statement. Assuming that your information is coming from user input I'd do it like so:

```
$input = Input::only(['province', 'city', 'speciality']);
$user = new User;

foreach($input as $key => $value) {
     if(!empty($value)) {
         $user = $user->where($key, $value);
     }
}

$users = $user->get();

return View::make('foo', compact('users'));
```

Comment: so if I initialize a new User object outside and add where clauses later, its OK?